# I need help on how to graph $2x+1=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want steps on how to graph because i have many equations like this and I have no idea how to graph and get $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Nemo: in this case there's no way to get $y$. You have only this $x=\frac{-1}{2}$

Comment: Are you sure you have to graph this "equation"? Or you have to graph the function f(x)=2x+1 ? Since 2x+1=0 is a set which contains one element.

Comment: $2x+1=0\iff 2x = -1\iff x = -\frac{1}{2}$.  There is absolutely no restriction on what $y$ can be in this case and $y$ does not change with respect to $x$.  You could draw a one-dimensional graph, showing the real number line, and just plot your single point at $x=-\frac{1}{2}$.  If you really want a two-dimensional graph, that would be a vertical line at $x=-\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

In general, equations in the form $ax+b=0$ are solved as follows.
$$ax+b=0$$
$$ax=-b$$
$$x=\frac{-b}{a}$$
Which is literally just a vertical line at $x=\frac{-b}{a}$.